# RoR Summation Issue

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with my Ruby application. I created users who are associated with a resource (resource_id). The working hours of the users indicate the capacity of the resource. The resource table should display the total capacity of the resources. The total capacity of the resource results from the sum of the capacities of the users assigned to the respective resource. However, in the resource table, the same capacity is displayed for each resource (the sum of all resources).

As an an example:

I have 2 use, which each work 8 hours:

User 1: capacity 8, resource_id 1
User 1: capacity 8, resource_id 2

Now there should be 2 resources in the resource table, each with a capacity of 8. With me however both resources with a capacity of 16 ..

Here are the corresponding index files, controllers and models.

resources.index

```
<% provide(:title, 'Ressourcen') %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Ressourcen</h1>

<table id="resources" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gesamtkapazität</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <% @resources.each do |resource| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= resource.name %></td>
      <td><%= User.sum(:capacity, :conditions => {:resource_id => resource}) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Anzeigen', resource %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Entfernen', resource, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Sind Sie sich sicher?' } %></td>
  <% end %>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

resource.model:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  def resource_params
    params.require(:resource).permit(:created_at, :name, :ocr, :cost, :oce)
  end

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {maximum: 50}

  has_many :procedure_resources, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :procedures, through: :procedure_resources
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

resource.controller:

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_resource, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /resources
  # GET /resources.json
  def index
    @resources = Resource.all
    @procedures = Procedure.all
    @project = Project.find(1)
  end


  def show
    @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def set_resource
    @resource = Resource.find(params[:id])
  end

  def resource_params
    params.require(:resource).permit(:name, :oce, :oce, :cost, :ocr)
  end
end
```

users.model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :resource
```

Does anyone know how I managed it, that it only shows the capacity of the respective resource in the resource.index?
The error must be in the resource.index with the following line:

`<td> <% = User.sum (: capacity,: conditions => {: resource_id => resource})%> </ td>`

or?

Best regards,
Phillip

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When asking a question you should post the minimal needed code to replicate or see the problem. Most of the code in the question is irrelevant to the problem and will make it less likely that people on here will try to solve it. Please update the question with only the needed code.

Comment: Thank you! I've try to delete the irrelevant code :)